# how can i set a mesh control point value use maya python api

Tags: python-2.7, maya

I want use maya python api to get a mesh control point attribute and set a new value.but I don't have a clue.
like mel command  setAttr 'pCubeShape1.pnts[3].pntx' 2;
but i want to use api or some quicker way..
Thnks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maya python iterating a big number of vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808363/maya-python-iterating-a-big-number-of-vertex)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in exactly the same way....

```
from maya import cmds
cmds.setAttr('pCubeShape1.pnts[3].pntx', 2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basically a python mesh deformer: select a mesh shape and run it.
It queries and sets vertex positions in a loop over the mesh vertex iterator.

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om2
sel = om2.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList()
sel_it = om2.MItSelectionList(sel)
mobj = sel_it.getDependNode()
print(om2.MFnDependencyNode(mobj).name())

cntr = 0.0    
vit = om2.MItMeshVertex(mobj)
while not vit.isDone():
    pos = vit.position()
    pos[0] = cntr
    vit.setPosition(pos)
    vit.next()
    cntr+=0.01
```

I'm recommending to look into Maya python plugins/deformers examples. You can do really cool stuff with just 1 single compute()/deform() function.